# Can't use default Bootstrap colors in Sass

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, sass

I imported the bootstrap scss using the following code

```
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

I can even change default bootstrap variables like :

```
$border-radius: 1rem;
```

But the thing is that I can't use bootstrap colors in my own css selectors like this, Why the following code doesn't work? It doesn't change the color.

```css
aside a {
  color: $success;
}
```

Comment: use !important to the style.

Comment: Where are you importing `bootstrap`? At the top of your SCSS?

Comment: @RayeesAC there is absolutely no reason to use `!important`. That should be a last resort. It's better to use more specific selectors than use `!important`. Also, if OP is using bootstrap - why would they use `!important` to override what they are already getting?

Comment: Voting to close since this isn't a bootstrap issue, but rather another rule set to `!important` that was overriding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use like this

```
@import "style/variables";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

@import "style/my_other_SCSS
```

in variables.scss

```
$border-radius: 1rem;
```

in my_other_SCSS.scss

```
aside a {
  color: $success;
}
```

this will work.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `$success` isn't set as a SASS/SCSS variable, but rather a CSS var, e.g `--success`:

```css
aside a {
  color: var(--success);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<aside>
<a href="#">link</a>
</aside>
```

Here's the documentation:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#available-variables

Comment: I tried it like this. doesn't work. still, color doesn't change. And I'm importing Bootstrap locally with npm.

Comment: Run the code snippet. It works here and would be the same even if importing bootstrap locally with npm. The CDN is the css version of what you have.

Comment: You might need to add more information to your original question about where you are importing Bootstrap into your SCSS file. Do you have other CSS overriding the `a` tags?

Comment: Exactly that was the main issue.

Comment: plus I changed the value success color. If I code it like  `color: var(--success);`  it shows the changed value of success. But If I code like  `color:$success`  it shows the default bootstrap value.

Answer (score -2):

There was another **!important** rule in the stylesheet that was overriding the link color.

```css
a {
    color : white !important
}
```